# How do I read the output of the devel module?

Tags: debugging, entities

This is not asking where to find the output from devel, as I know where to find it. The question is how to read it and make sense of it. I need to find a field from a field collection, and then reference that field in a computed field; I am totally lost -- that is to say that I know where both the devel output is, and I have a view with a global php field that has `print_r($data)` in it, both of which show me a bunch of names and php stuff I am unfamiliar with. I am an intermediate novice with php, so please take that into account.

Here is what my dpm($data) looks like, with the field that I desire expanded:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried with devel function dpm($data)? That's much better than print_r.

Comment: @JoseDaniel I may have tried that in the tpl file for the site or something, but I can't remember the result. Do you think it is possible for me to put dpm($data) in the same place that I have print_r($data) (in a global php field in a view), or is there some other place I should place it?

Comment: Yes, you should try to use dpm() function where is your variable $data.

Comment: Awesome that looks great... but now I need an answer to my original question... How do I read that? Or more specifically how do I get a field from that output? I found the value in the data presented by dpm(), but I don't know how to reference that field.

Comment: I think the best approach is to get the collection values with field_get_items() and the iterate over the collection to get the data you need. Take a look to this solution: https://drupal.org/node/1208064#comment-4753358

Comment: @JoseDaniel I plan on using that solution, when I get the field name that I am looking for. The problem is though that that solution requires a field name, but I am unsure of how to suss it out the output from dpm().

Comment: I understand. Usually fields are arrays inside objects and you can see the structure with dpm(). Is there some way you can show and screenshot of the collapsed print?

Comment: Ya I edited my question with it. The field that is expanded down to 'value' is the field I want.

Comment: Try with this one: $data->field_field_percent[0]['raw']['value']

Comment: ok so this line in #4 of the link you provided about is where I would change the field name? `$foo_fields[$i] = field_get_items('field_collection_item', $field_collection_item_field, 'field_foo');` to something like `$foo_fields[$i] = field_get_items('field_collection_items', $data->field_field_percent[0]['raw']['value'], 'field_field_percent'`

Comment: Yes, I think that is the place where you have to use it.